# Unable to access validation errors in view

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have set up a controller with some validation.

```
public function attemptLogin()
{
    $rules = array(
        'email'=>'required|email', 
        'password'=>'required'
    );


    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all() , $rules);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);
    };
}
```

If I output the messages directly in the controller

```
$messages = $validator->messages();
print_R($messages->all());
```

I get the validation errors - however if I redirect:

```
return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);
```

The `$errors` array available in the view is always coming up empty.

Comment: Laravel 4 is still in BETA - so i advise you head on over to www.Laravel.io

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [laravel four documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation)

> Note that when validation fails, we pass the Validator instance to the
>   Redirect using the `withErrors` method. This method will flash the error
>   messages to the session so that they are available on the next
>   request.

Variable `$errors` it's not an array.

> The `$errors` variable will be an instance of
>   `MessageBag`.

<del>For some reason I don't really like @seamlss idea.</del>
You can use this <del>instead.</del>

```
@if(Session::has('errors'))
<? $errors = Session::get('errors'); ?>
<div class="alert alert-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <ul>
        <li id="form-errors" >
            <h3> {{ $errors->first('email') }}</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

*I've used some `bootstrap` components, don't get confused, the only thing you need is the lines with the curly braces and the magical @ sign.*

From [laravel docs error-messages-and-views](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#error-messages-and-views)

> So, it is important to note that an $errors variable will always be
>   available in all of your views, on every request, allowing you to
>   conveniently assume the $errors variable is always defined and can be
>   safely used.

You can also check [this](http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-using-forms-and-the-validator)

```
@if( $errors->has('email') )
    <div class="control-group error">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
            <span class="help-inline">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: @FMaz008 Why do you presume this is not `blade` syntax?

Answer (score 5):

I've had success redirecting using `->withErrors($validation)`

And then in the view checking the condition `@if( $errors->count() > 0 )`...

```
@if( $errors->count() > 0 )
    <p>The following errors have occurred:</p>

    <ul id="form-errors">
        {{ $errors->first('username', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        {{ $errors->first('password', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        {{ $errors->first('password_confirmation', '<li>:message</li>') }}
    </ul>   
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);
```

or

```
return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator->messages());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility when you have difficulty showing errors, and when they are passed correctly via `->withErrors()`. If you redirect to a controller action that has to perform any sort of its own state checking and itself calls `->withErrors()`, it will shadow the `$errors` first injected.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
return Redirect::to('login')->with('errors',$validator->errors->all());
```

then from your view loop through this errors

```
foreach($errors as $error) {
    print $error;
}
```